# How to inform users that webapplication does not support IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I have web application and I do not really care about IE6 users. However I would like to have some kind of feature that would inform users that they are using IE6 and that their browser is not supported. I was thinking about two possible solutions:

1. pop-out window (probably Javascript) with text informing the user on every page he visits
2. some special page with information, that user would be redirected to whenever he tries to access my application

Both solutions will be sufficient, however I would prefer the second one. Probably some magic javascript needs to be involved, can anyone could please provide a solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would probably use a [conditional comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to show a bar or a box in clear view of the user on the page.  JavaScript/Meta redirection is usually rather annoying for everyone involved.

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <div id="IE6Div">This Web Application does not support Internet Explorer 6.  
         Click <a href="/noIE6.htm">here</a> for more information.</div>
<![endif]-->
```

You can style it however you like then.  I recommend a big bold bar at the top of your page that is stuck even when scrolling, turn off javascript and refresh a stack overflow page for an example.

If you're insistent on the JS method, try [this script](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) from Quirksmode for detecting the browser and the version, then use `window.location.replace(newUrl)` for the redirection.

Comment: I agree with the bar, JavaScript is **not** the way to handle this. A simple bar at the top is enough to notify users. I'd also like to point out that it's not a matter of your website supporting IE6, it's IE6 not supporting everything on your website.

Answer (score 10):

[Help rid the world of IE6 with one line of javascript!](https://code.google.com/archive/p/sevenup)

---

Update:
In case of IE6 users with JavaScript *turned off*, you can use a conditional comment. (graceful degradation)

```
<!--[if IE 6]>  
<span> THIS WEBSITE DOES NOT SUPPORT Internet Explorer 6. PLEASE UPGRADE. </span>  
<![endif]-->
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://sevenup.googlecode.com/files/sevenup_plugin_black.jpg))</sub>

Comment: @Andy: yeah :). straight from ie6 to chrome and firefox ... Feels so progressive! :P

Comment: One thing to note is that this sort of thing could also be done with a conditional comment, so it would show to users with JS switched off.

Answer (score 2):

Redirect users to http://ie6funeral.com/.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good solution: http://www.ie6update.com/

It shows IE6-visitors a message that looks like IE's own information Bart, but instead of offering an ActiveX plugin, it offers a browser update.

All you need to do is include a small piece of js-code in your site.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with 2. Point is that you can optimize this page to show decently on IE 6 - and this is not a pop-out.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx), that's usually the only thing these are used for anyways.

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
window.location = 'new page';
</SCRIPT>
<![endif]-->
```

Of course **I would not use JavaScript because if they have it disabled it won't do anything**, I would use a [meta refresh](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H76.html) instead and put it in the head.

Comment: JavaScript is just as bad. I have all scripts disabled by default for every website, I only enable scripts for websites I trust.

Comment: .. Disabling JS is like running a PC with no hard-disk so no virus can get on it. The web is no longer about static content and hasn't been for years.

Comment: The point is not to protect yourself from viruses, it's to stop annoying pointless scripts and videos from automatically executing when you visit a page. Personally, it irritates the *hell* out of me when I visit a page and it automatically starts playing music or something. My reaction: automatic back button.