# How do I make the background image change on hover, for my span?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a span:

```
<span class="myspan"></span>

.myspan{
background: url(image.png) top left no-repeat;
}
```

How do I make it so that when people hover my span, it shows "image_hover.png"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.myspan:hover{
background-image:url('image_hover.png');
}
```

But what you really would want to do is make one image with both states, natural state and hover state, one beside the other. Then you would have:

```
.myspan{
width: *the width of only one state. aka half the width of the whole image*
background:url('image.png') top left no-repeat;
}

.myspan:hover{
background-postion:right;
}
```

That way only one image is loaded and on hover, it just moves it left to right. Displaying only one half of the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the :hover pseudo class to every element:

```
.myspan:hover
{
    background-image: url(image_hover.png);
}
```

Internet Explorer 6 won’t care … but who cares about IE 6? :)

Comment: for ie6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423516/how-to-inform-users-that-webapplication-does-not-support-ie6/2423540#2423540

Answer (score 2):

Alex,

You can try

```
.myspan:hover{background:url('image_hover.png') top left no-repeat;}
```

You can also combine image.png and image_hover.png into one png image and simply move the position on hover. Your png would look like this: http://www.missgoodytwoshoes.com/images/nav_shop.png

And your code would look like this:

```
<span class="myspan"></span>

.myspan{
background: url(image.png) top left no-repeat;
height: 37px;
}
.myspan:hover
{
background-position:0 -37px;
}
```

Comment: Looks like @Vian beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 0):

Use the :hover pseudo class:

```
.myspace:hover
{
    backbround: url(image-over.png) top left no-repeat;
}
```